# How can I get the value in % relative div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i write function which output top and left all div within div id=container

```
   var main = $('#container'),
res = $('#result'),
bw = parseInt(main.css('border-left-width'), 10),
mT = main.offset().top + bw,
mL = main.offset().left + bw;
$('#btn1').on('click', function () {
    var allCoords = $('div', main).map(function () {
        return getCoords(this);
    }).get().join('<br>'); 

    res.html(allCoords); });
function getCoords(el) {
    var $that = $(el),
    pos = $that.offset(),
    posTop = pos.top - mT,
    posLeft = pos.left - mL;
    var pos = el.id + ' top: ' + posTop + 'px; left: ' + posLeft + 'px;';
    return pos;}
```

How can I get the value(left and top) in % relative div id container
please help me.Thank

Answer (score 0):

Use math formula 100*yoursreensize/yourelementdivorsomething, like this:

```js
var width = $(window).width();

var left = $('#me').position().left;

var percent = parseInt(100*left/width);
alert(percent);
```

```css
#me{
  position:relative;
  left:20%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="me">Me</div>
```